# C# Databinding: Create object if null

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a report object (i.e. a business object) which has several dozen fields to populate.  Each field by itself has `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented.  There is an accessor property for the active report called `ActiveReport`.

What I want to do is be able to Close the current report, without necessarily opening a new one, and be able to automatically create a report object when the user starts to enter data again.

Here is a rough idea of the structure.  `ActiveReport` is the current report.  The GUI is able to directly set the fields of the subclass (name/email) through binding.  I want a new `BusinessObject` to be created when name is being set, but ActiveReport is null.  One additional caveat, the report object is auto-generated from XSD files, so I'd rather not have to modify those.

```
class ControlClass {
    public BusinessObject ActiveReport { get; set; }
}

class BusinessObject {
    UserInfo field1 { get; set; }
}

class UserInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    DependencyProperty name;
    DependencyProperty email;
}
```

I thought of the following scenarios:

- Accessor property.

  - The binding does not seem to use the accessor.
- Inserting a check into all event handlers.

  - I'd rather not have to resort to this -- this breaks the rationale behind using MVVM.
- Multibinding

  - This would require the use of a converter class and instance, and that seems like overkill.
- Converter

I thought to ask if there were any other good programming models for this in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a behavior.
in it, you check if (AssociatedObject.DataContext as ReportObject) is null
and if it is, clear all your fields / set your datacontext / whatever

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
public class ControlClass
{
     public BusinessObject ActiveReport { get; set; }


     private UserInfo _editableUserData 
     public UserInfo EditableUserData
     {
         get { return _editableUserData; }
         set
         { 
             if (_editableUserData != null)
                   _editableUserData.PropertyChanged -= UserDataChanged;

             _editableUserData = value;

             if (_editableUserData != null)
                  _editableUserData.PropertyChanged += UserDataChanged;

             RaisePropertyChanged("EditableUserData");
         }
     }

     private void UserDataChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
           if (ActiveReport == null)
                ActiveReport = new BusinessObject(EditableUserData);
     }
}
```